# solve for $\log_x ( \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{x} ) \gt \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{x} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_x ( \dfrac{5}{2} - \dfrac{1}{x} ) \gt  \dfrac{5}{2} - \dfrac{1}{x} $

I found the domain which is $x \gt \dfrac{2}{5} \;$ and $x \neq 1.$

I tried making two cases $x \gt 1\;$ and $x\lt 1\;$ and solving it. But that only gives me a lot of terms.

I was also thinking about making a graph.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing to do is to plot the function $f(x)=lhs-rhs$; then, locate the roots more or less accurately from the graph and polish them using, say, Newton method.

Answer (score 1):

We get
$$\frac{2}{5}<x<0.54568953436119576369$$ or
$$1<x<1.38188769407987911316$$

Comment: (+1) I don't really know what the OP was expecting for working. The intersections of these two graphs do not have closed forms (as far as I know).

Comment: @PeterForeman can you please explain? (your comment)

Comment: @swarnim In order to solve an inequality, it must be possible to first solve the same equality. The solutions to $\log_x{\left(\frac52-\frac1x\right)}=\frac52-\frac1x$ cannot be found exactly and must be approximated using numerical methods.

Comment: I have used the Newton-Raphson method

Comment: Newton method is fine with equation but how can be helpful with inequalities?.

Comment: You can consider the inequality as an equation

Comment: The fact that you know the roots of the equation does not tell where the inequality holds except graphing the function $lhs-rhs$.

Comment: This have i done.